# On avoiding a linear subspace of an algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} R_n$ be a standard graded algebra over an infinite field $K = R_0$. Suppose $depth \ R > 0$. Thus there exist linear forms which are non-zero divisors of $R$.

Let $a \geq 2$ and let $V$ be a $K$-subspace of $R_a$. Assume that

$$\dim V + \dim R_{a-1} < \dim R_a.$$
Then DOES there exist a  linear form $x$ which is a non-zero divisor on $R$ such that

$$V \cap xR_{a-1} = 0.$$

I think the assertion is true. However I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: So given the statement, it sounds as if you already know this to be true. In which case, what are you looking for? A reference for this fact?

Comment: Hi 
I do not know whether this is true, although I strongly suspect it to be true

Comment: What is a linear form in this context ? Is it just a homogeneous element ? 

Comment: it is just a homogenous element 